# How do I add a product specific facebook share button to order confirmation page?

Tags: facebook, share

I've looked high and low around the web looking for an answer to my question but the answers just don't quite give me what I'm looking for...

I have an e-commerce site where I'd like to add a share button to the order confirmation page that, when clicked, shares the specific product they have just purchased.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Each product needs to have a unique URL in order to be shared. This is the URL that you will use when generating your share button.

When [implementing a share button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/), you'll need the JavaScript SDK (as mentioned in the link) and once you have that, all you'll need to do is have this HTML on your page:

`<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://your-product-url" data-type="button_count"></div>`

The `data-href` attribute is what you want to be dynamic and swap it out for each product you want to share.